# Sinatra rendering .md.erb templates, if present, otherwise .md

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Using sinatra, I can tell it to render a markdown template, e.g. view/my_template.md passing the template name like so: `markdown :my_template`.

But I want to put it through erb processing first, so my file is called `view/my_template.md.erb`

but...  I also want my code to work either way. I want it to use an .md.erb file if present, but otherwise an .md file.

I wondered if there's a standard way of doing that in sinatra, rather than coding the logic of this fallback myself. The following works, but seems inelegant:

```ruby
get '/route/to/my/page' do
  begin
    # Try to do erb processing into a string with the file view/my_template.md.erb
    md_content = erb :my_template.md, :layout => false
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
    # Set it to use the view/my_template.md file instead
    md_template = :my_template
  end
  # Either way we do the markdown rendering and use the erb layouts
  markdown md_content || md_template, :layout_engine => :erb, :renderer => MARKDOWN_RENDERER
end
```

Rescue Errno::ENOENT seems inelegant. Also the code is confusing where I specify a name with '.md' in order for it to pick up the '.md.erb' file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any kind of automatic detection of templates present, nor 'standard' way to do what you want. Sinatra's rendering methods like `markown` or `erb` are just a bunch of one-liner wrappers around more general `render` method, which does only what its name says.

In your case, manual detection of preferred template and its type should be simple and doesn't need to throw exceptions.

```
get '/route/to/my/page' do
  tpl_path = Dir.glob('views/my_template.md{,.erb}').sort.last
  tpl_name = File.basename(tpl_path, '.*').to_sym
  tpl_type = File.extname(tpl_path)

  erb_output = erb(tpl_name) if tpl_type == '.erb'
  markdown(erb_output || tpl_name)
end
```

`Dir.glob` will pick `my_template.md.erb` over `my_template.md`. Also, with `tpl_type` you avoid confusion about original template type.

Comment: Ah yeah I thought about doing it that way, but then building my own file path outside of the framework also feels inelegant. It's good to avoid the exception flow though I guess. ...Anyway, you've answered my question, in that there is no more built-in sinatra way of doing this thing.